# Can I speed up this simple Dask script to get a total row count across multiple Feather dataframes?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have data in `C:\script\data\YYYY\MM\data.feather`

To understand Dask better, I am trying to optimize a simple script which gets the row count from each of those files and sums them up. There are almost 100 million rows across 200 files.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import feather
from dask.distributed import Client,LocalCluster
from dask import delayed

counts = []
with LocalCluster() as cluster, Client(cluster) as client:
  for f in dates:
    df = delayed(feather.read_feather)(f'data\{f.year}\{f.month:02}\data.feather',columns=['colA','colB'])
    counts.append(df.shape[0])

tot = sum(counts)
print(dd.compute(tot))
```

I've included both colA and colB in the read_feather because I want to eventually move to counting distinct values in different timespans. What I see in the task stream is read_feather firing off at about 2 seconds each, as well as a number of `disk-write-read_feather` and `disk-read-getattr` taking 2-4 seconds each. If I run read_feather in it's own script on a single file, it takes about 0.4 seconds to complete. Is the additional time for read_feather due to the parallelism? Also, do the `disk-*` tasks mean it is reading the file, then writing to disk, and reading it again? I'd thought Dask would read in the file, count the rows, and store that number for summing later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance of `disk-write-read_feather` and `disk-read-getattr` (should be red on your dashboard view) suggests that the dataframe is large in memory and is indeed being cached to disc - which is totally unhelpful in this case.

When you do

```
df = ...
df.shape[0]
```

this creates a chain of three delayed calls (i.e., tasks) for each partition, one to load, one to select the attribute and one to select the index. It seems that these calls are not being fused into one, and you have large intermediate results.

Instead you could make sure to combine the calls, and not have big results:

```
@dask.delayed
def get_size(f):
    df = feather.read_feather(f'data\{f.year}\{f.month:02}\data.feather',columns=['colA','colB'])
    return df.shape[0]

counts = [get_size(f) for f in dates]
```

However, I don't know if loading feather is expected to play nicely with threading, or if you may be simply maxing out you IO. Your dashboard and system monitoring tools might tell you more.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Your way was much faster. I initially tried your solution with `[delayed(get_size(f)) for f in dates]` since I had not imported dask at first. The task stream and graph did not populate until right before completing. Did not realize the decorator would make a big difference. With your exact solution, the stream is much more compact, updated live, and finishes about 5x faster.

Comment: Ignore the comment above. Called delayed on the result, not not the function.